# Trigger a jQuery Function when linked is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have a comparison table that has about 20 items. I would like when a link is clicked it will show more information on that item. I can do this by using the following function:

```
$(function(){
  $('.show').click(function() {
    $('#keywords').fadeIn('slow');
 });
});
```

However as I mentioned there are twenty items and repeating the above code could get cumbersome.

How do I create a function that would show the div below the link that is clicked? On top of that if a div is open or visable and another item is clicked I want the other item to close or fade out and then the other to show.

Here is my HTML for part of the page:

```
<tr class="second">
  <td class="cat" style="width: 33%;">
    <div>
      <a class="show" href="#"> Mobile Keywords</a>
    </div>
      <div id="keywords" class="hide">
         p>Info Here</p>
    </div>
 </td>

 <td style="width: 33%;">
    <i class="icon-ok"></i>
 </td>

 <td class="" style="width: 33%;">
     <i class="icon-ok"></i>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr class="second">
  <td class="cat" style="width: 33%;">
    <div>
      <a class="show" href="#">Another Category</a>
    </div>
      <div id="category-2" class="hide">
         p>Info Here</p>
    </div>
 </td>

 <td style="width: 33%;">
    <i class="icon-ok"></i>
 </td>

 <td class="" style="width: 33%;">
     <i class="icon-ok"></i>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I assume this can be done using the `this` property but I do not know how to implement `this` as I am not familiar enough with JS.

To summarize:  How do I have a link in this table that will be clicked and then the link shows the appropriate div without having to create a repeat the code for every item?

Comment: The `id="keywords"` element cannot repeat using that ID, what ID do you use so I can give you a correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.show').click(function() {
    $('.hide').hide();
    $(this).closest('td.cat').find('.hide').fadeIn();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/G7mkA/1/)

edit: Added hide functionality as requested in the question.

---

### Explanation

In the code above, `this` references the element that triggered the click event handler (the clicked anchor element).

Then, `this` is wrapped inside a jQuery object and we traverse the DOM tree up to a common ancestor using the [`.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method, from there we find the hidden element to display.

The `$('.hide').hide()` in the first line is self-explanatory, it hides all elements with the `hide` class before animating the `fadeIn` of the one to be displayed.

Comment: One more question - Is it possible to make the div that is visible fade out when the div not visible is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('.show').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().next('div').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});​
```

Utilizing the [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method, we can traverse up the dom one level, then using [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) we get the *next* immediate div, which seems to follow sequence with your markup.

Answer (score 0):

Using your HTML markup, this might work.  Will hide currently shown div, only if its not the same element and show the desired one.

```
$(function(){
  $('.show').click(function() {
    if ( !$(this).hasClass('shown') )
    {
        $('.shown').removeClass('shown').parent().siblings('div').hide();
        $(this).addClass('shown').parent().siblings('div').fadeIn('slow');
    }
 });
});​
```

**Edit**: working code.

Comment: `if ( $(this).not('.shown') )` wut? You realize `.not` always returns a jQuery object which evaluates to true right? Use [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) instead.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Hah, yeah, end of the work day here, should stop trying to answer questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $('.show').click(function() {
    $('.hide').hide();
    $(this).parent('div').next('div').fadeIn('slow');
 });
});
```

Uses this (as you expected), looks for its parent div, and then looks for its first sibling div.

Edited to include the hide functionality.